# two linear layouts in the same screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

hi im trying to design my app for both android phone and tablet. So i already had it designed but needed to redesign for scaling purposes for different screens.

[image]

This is the layout im going for.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">
  
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
         />
  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ClickTourismButton"
        android:text="@string/Tourism" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:text="@string/Nearby" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Favourites" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"  
        android:text="@string/Map" />
         
    </LinearLayout>   
    
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
       
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"      
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate1" />
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <ListView
         
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" /> 
    
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i run the app the two linear layouts are on top of each other?? or the map fragment which is seen above as the black rectangle takes up all the screen??? Ive no idea what im doing wrong, ive looked through several tutorials and t seems right?

Need assistance please

thanks

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ClickTourismButton"
        android:text="@string/Tourism" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:text="@string/Nearby" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Favourites" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"  
        android:text="@string/Map" />

    </LinearLayout>   


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"      
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@color/red"    
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

one component takes up each side??
its divided in two but the map fragment takes up all of one side and the first listview takes up all of the other???

Comment: make the android:weight="1" for both the linear layouts. that will divide the screen equally between them.

Comment: its now divided in two but one component takes up all the space on each side? how do i give each component space?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Change your orientation of both child LinearLayouts to `VERTICAL`
2. For top remove Relative and use LinearLayout with orientation `HORIZONTAL`
   and have `weightSum=2`
3. Now in both child linearlayout views give `layout_width="0dp"`  and `layout_weight="1"`

---

Example XML for you : http://pastebin.com/2MCBN9qk

Comment: is that all i should change @MKJPrarekh as now its divied in two but the map fragment takes up all of one side and the first listview takes up all of the other???

Comment: the layout looks good. The listviews however just appear as thin lines?

Comment: Thanks @MKJParekh your solution helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing RelativeLayout with LinearLayout, please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou) for a deeper understanding about the different types of layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using weightSum 
and add your linear layouts inside a Relative layout for better positioning.