# Android Vertical Layout : all my text controls render at the top

Tags: android

I just want to show vertically a title, a picture, a description but instead I got all text controls above the picture whereas I did specify a vertical layout (android:orientation="vertical") in fragment showed by ViewPager :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your parent layout is relative but you have coded your child elements in a way it is done for linearlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:orientation="vertical"` is for LinearLayout, change this to a LinearLayout or if you want to use a RelativeLayout define exactly where views are supposed to be displayed relative to other views. More info here: [What are the differences between LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, and AbsoluteLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou)

Answer (score 1):

use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout or just implement Eng. Samer T solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using **relativelayout**

In relative layout no matter with orientation

Just use below snippet

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="section" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"       />
```

Comment: use  android:layout_below and  android:layout_above