# Vertically center two switches

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch

I want to center two switches as I did with the textviews but I've tried all the possible options without success.

This is a brief version of the code:

```
<LinearLayout [...]
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="NOTIFICATIONS" />

        <TextView [...] />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swnotif"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Switch [...] />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i tested

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="NOTIFICATIONS" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MUTE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/swnotif"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/swnotif1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But now I've tried using Horizontal LinearLayouts instead of FrameLayouts and also works, what is the best solution?

Comment: nice to hear that.. please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4905403/3442067)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `gravity` attribute doesn't seem to affect `Switch` views like it does text and other views. A workaround is to wrap each of the switches in a `RelativeLayout` like the following:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here bro,

I adjust margin left and right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="New"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="New"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Set center_vertical gravity to TextView and Switch parent LinearLayout :

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```