# Android Studio Objects Position on Emulator/SmartPhone

Tags: android-studio, position, scaling, android-layout-weight

I created icons and buttons for my app and put them in my Android Studio project.

In the Emulator it looks like this:

[image: Emulator View]

But on my phone it looks like this:

[image: Phone View]

What can I do or how can I scale the icons for every resolution perfectly?

Thanks for every answer.

Layout xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="1052dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_x="-321dp"
        android:layout_y="137dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barline"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_x="-10dp"
        android:layout_y="478dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bewertung"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_x="270dp"
        android:layout_y="477dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bekanntheit"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_x="172dp"
        android:layout_y="477dp"
        android:background="@drawable/crew"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_x="85dp"
        android:layout_y="477dp"
        android:background="@drawable/einkaufswagen"
        android:contentDescription="" />
```

Comment: Please include your xml layout file. You will also need to use `layout_weight`. Stack Overflow is full of this kind of questions. Please search thoroughly first, then ask if you have any inquiries or problems.

Comment: I added the xml file to the question..

Comment: ok, I need to add a comment..

Comment: Hello SimonVJava, I have just added a slight edit to my answer. You only need to specify a `layout_height` for each view instead of using `wrap_content` because `wrap_content` will use the drawable's default height and won't wrap it according to the children height, and I'm sure this is what happened to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` with orientation set to horizontal, then define `layout_weight` for each view you have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/barline">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/bewertung"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/bekanntheit"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@drawable/crew"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:background="@drawable/einkaufswagen"
        android:contentDescription="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. <3 Thats so polite. Have you already created published Apps?

Comment: :c Nothing is working.. If I want to put 1 Objekt down left, all other Objekts move to. Sorry I'm a beginner and only 14 :c

Comment: No problem, and yes I have published 2 apps. You can check them from my profile. I am also 16, somewhere near your age! :) Can you please explain a little bit more? Where did your objects move? I'll be glad to help you. :)

Comment: Okay, I'll check out your 2 Apps afterwards! So I'll try explain a little bit more, whats my problem is..

Comment: If I want to move a objekt (invisible) to another place like this: http://prntscr.com/9weht0                                                                                                            This will happen:                                                                                                     http://prntscr.com/9wekh1

Comment: You posted the same link in your last comment, but anyway I think I got what you meant. You will need to understand the difference between LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. You can check the accepted answer in this link, including the link he mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou  You will need to use LinearLayout and RelativeLayout together in your case. If you want me to create the layout for you, just draw what you want on any program or paper, and I will create it for you.

Comment: But it's better to understand all types of layout too. 

Comment: Ok, thanks again for your answer! I can send you the .png files and a image how it should look like.. The .pngs are for another projekt, but I think this doesnt matter.. How can I send you the files??

Comment: PS: Can you open a chat?? I think we shouldn't do that in the comments.. (:

Comment: @SimonVJava I don't know how to start a chat here. If you could start it, it will be great! Sorry for the late response. :)

Comment: I don't know too :c But how can I send you the files??

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe try chatting with me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102175/discussion-between-hussein-el-feky-and-simonvjava