# How to overlap imageviews in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am facing an issue with the space between the views. Using a LinerLayout and dynamically adding views(ImageViews) to the linear layout.

I want to adjust the space between the imageview. I want them to have an overlap - when a new view is added.

[Current view of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vgsh.png)

Currently a blue back ground is applied to highlight the two linear layouts.

code to add Image view to the existing layout

```
dealerImages= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dealerImages);
    dealerImages.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

ImageView view = new ImageView(BlackJack.this);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
    dealerImages.addView(view);
```

Every time I add a new view - I want to specify the relative position to the old view. I want the **new view to start from the center of the last view** in the layout.

Please let me know if you need any additional details. Please suggest if I need to use any other layout to make things easier.

Edit - Posting the code here

```
 playerLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dealerLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


private void dealTwoCardsEach(){
    player.addCard(hit());
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(BlackJack.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(getResourceId(player.getFirstCard()));
    playerImages.addView(imageView, player.getCards().size()-1);

    dealer.addCard(hit());
    imageView = new ImageView(BlackJack.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(getResourceId(dealer.getFirstCard()));
    dealerImages.addView(imageView);

    player.addCard(hit());
    if(player.getCount() == 21)
        player.setBlackJack(true);

    imageView = new ImageView(BlackJack.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(getResourceId(player.getSecondCard()));
    updateMarginForPlayer(); // updating start margin
    playerImages.addView(imageView, player.getCards().size()-1, playerLayoutParams);

    dealer.addCard(hit());
}


private void updateMarginForPlayer(){
        playerLayoutParams.setMarginStart(playerLayoutParams.getMarginStart()+100);
}
```

Please not i am not setting any margin for the first card for the player. 
I can see both the cards until here. First Image with start margin of 0 and the second Image with start margin of 100.

```
private void handleHit(){
    Card c1 = hit();
    player.addCard(c1);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(getResourceId(c1));
    updateMarginForPlayer();
    playerImages.addView(imageView, playerLayoutParams);

}
```

On click of the 'Hit' button is when handleHit() gets called. and the new images being added are making all the images from 2nd till the currrent view invisible. I can only see the first and last(latest added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LinearLayout` stacks views in a linear fashion one after another. You can never create an overlapping layout with just a `LinearLayout` it will always stack it next to the current view based on whatever orientation it is defined with.

What you are looking for is `RelativeLayout` in a relative layout, the views are stacked dependent to each other, and since it is also a `ViewGroup` class the same code will work for it too.

Check the relative layout doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and a brief post of their comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou)

Also, when you create a child in relative layout you can add params to where it goes or simply add a margin which is half the size of your original layout to stack them from centre!

You dont have to call the update params, instead add params to the imageview.

```
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(getResourceId(c1));
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(100,0,0,0);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    playerImages.addView(imageView, playerLayoutParams);
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be working. But now after adding a new view at the specified margin - i cant see the views below it. I can only see the first and the latest. Is there a attribute that I need to set to the child view before adding for them to be visible always.

Comment: they are not visible because they might be below the last view, can you post your code so i can edit it for you!

Comment: I edited the original question with the code. Please take a look.

Comment: check edit. check the part of your code inside handleHit()